# $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1 - z\bar{a}}$ interpretation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I recently started a complex-analysis course and our teacher proposed this exercise to us:

> Given $a, z \in \mathbb{C}$, consider the complex function 
>   $$ f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1 - z\bar{a}}.$$

I've proved already that either $\vert{z}\vert = 1$ or $\vert{a}\vert = 1$ implies
$$\left\vert{\frac{ z-a}{1 - z\bar{a}}}\right\vert = 1.$$

So, assume $\vert{a}\vert = 1$. My teacher asked 
"What exception needs to be made if $\vert{z}\vert = \vert{a}\vert = 1$?"

I can tell that if e.g., $ z = \frac{1}{\bar{a}}$, the function goes all the way to infinity, and that there is a $\frac{0}{0}$ type indetermination if $z = a$, but:

1. Is there any way to solve/understand the indetermination?
2. Or a way to interpret the function geometrically? I've already tried plotting it on davidbau.com, but I can't really understand what's going on.  Or is it just because I'm not used to complex functions?

Comment: If $|a|=1$, then $$\frac{z-a}{1-z\bar a}=-\frac1{\bar a}\frac{z-e^{i\arg(a)}}{z-e^{i\arg(a)}}=-e^{i\arg(a)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|a|=1$ then $\bar{a} = \frac 1a$, so that for $z \ne \frac{1}{\bar{a}}$
$$
f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1 - z\bar{a}} = \frac{z-a}{1 - z/a} = -a
$$
So $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=\frac{1}{\bar{a}}$, and can be continuously extended to the *constant* function $z \mapsto -a$.

Comment: did you want to write $z\mapsto -a$?